# Better sort algorithm

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Anybody know better and faster sort algorithm ? My code:

```
        var n;
    var i;
    for (n=0; n < mixedSMSPremiumSendedReceivedList.count; n++)
        for (i=n+1; i < mixedSMSPremiumSendedReceivedList.count; i++)
        {
            if (new Date(mixedSMSPremiumSendedReceivedList.get(n).smsData)> new Date(mixedSMSPremiumSendedReceivedList.get(i).smsData))
            {
                mixedSMSPremiumSendedReceivedList.move(i, n, 1);
                n=0;
            }
        }
```

I must sort List by Date(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)

Comment: I'd start by learning about various [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and their strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: But I must sort Date not integers....

Comment: What difference does it make?  Comparisons are comparisons.

Comment: OMG! This is (1) a badly worded question, (2) the proposed solution is awful. First problem is the use of the word `List`. The only thing I can think of is either Array or ListModel. Of which the answers would be different. Also, the proposed Date comparison is awful. It hints that the datatype chosen is incorrect. Fine, you may want "smsData" whatever that is, but, ultimately, it is for you to also store an easier to index field. e.g. "smsDataTime" which could be a normalized number of the date, e.g. `smsDataTime = (new Date(smsData)).getTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use sort on array with dates http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

I have just write few cases like this:

```
 MouseArea{
        id:block2mousearea

        anchors.fill:block2
        drag.target:block2

        drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis
        drag.minimumX:166
        drag.maximumX: 622
        drag.minimumY:180
        drag.maximumY: 371
        onClicked: {
            var dateRE = /^(\d{2})[\/\- ](\d{2})[\/\- ](\d{4})/;

            //dd/mm/yy format Ascending order
            function dmyOrdA(a, b){
              a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
              b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
              if (a>b) return 1;
              if (a <b) return -1;
              return 0;
            }

            //dd/mm/yy format descending
            function dmyOrdD(a, b){
              a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
              b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$2$1");
              if (a>b) return -1;
              if (a <b) return 1;
              return 0;
            }

            //mm/dd/yy format Ascending order
            function mdyOrdA(a, b){
              a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
              b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
              if (a>b) return 1;
              if (a <b) return -1;
              return 0;
            }

            //mm/dd/yy format descending
            function mdyOrdD(a, b){
              a = a.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
              b = b.replace(dateRE,"$3$1$2");
              if (a>b) return -1;
              if (a <b) return 1;
              return 0;
            }

            var dateArray = new Array('15/10/2000','28/05/1999','17/09/2005','06/12/2004','02/01/1998');
            dateArray.sort(dmyOrdA);

            console.log(dateArray);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a `QML` question it is likely you are working with `ListModel` and a visual component such as `ListView`. In this case, it actually isn't as essential that you have a high-performance sort. Let me explain. Any algorithm, regardless of how good it is, if it takes more than 50ms to execute the user will notice blocking in the main QML engine thread which makes the user will feel that the application is unresponsive at times. In fact, what is actually needed is a sort algorithm that works with Qt QML by calling `Qt.callLater` after a 50ms threshold is reached so that UI/UX maintains responsiveness. To that end, we can implement a simple binary insertion incremental merge sort that moves unsorted records to their sorted location. Because of this 50ms threshold, it gives the user to interrupt and change the sort conditions.

A simple solution may look like this:

- it has sortByDOB - for sorting dates normalized as with a ms epoch
- for comparison I provide sortByName
- the main loop has `Date.now() < ts + 50` to put a 50ms threshold
- it's incremental sort and QML friendly it reacts to `count` property binding changes, so, external code can append to this `ListModel` and trigger more sorting
- there's a property binding on the `sortCompare` property so if the conditions are changed, it will reset the incremental sort
- the `ListModel` is populated with sample data which illustrates the recommended storage of Dates, i.e. the normalizing to a ms epoch
- when unsorted items become sorted, we update `sortCount`.
- we have a `bool sorted` property which indicates sorting is complete when `sortCount >= count`
- we have another `bool sorting` property which indicates sorting is ongoing when `sorted === false`

```
ListView {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    model: sortListModel
    delegate: Text { text: name }
}
ListModel {
    id: sortListModel
    property int sortCount: 0
    property var sortCompare: sortByDOB
    property var sortByName: (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
    property var sortByDOB: (a, b) => a.dob - b.dob
    readonly property bool sorted: sortCount >= count
    readonly property bool sorting: !sorted
    onSortCompareChanged: Qt.callLater(resort)
    onCountChanged: {
        if (count === 0) { sortCount = 0; return; }
        Qt.callLater(sortStep);
    }
    function resort() {
        sortCount = 0;
        Qt.callLater(sortStep);
    }
    function sortStep() {
        for (let ts = Date.now(); sortCount < count && Date.now() < ts + 50; ) sortItem(sortCount++);
        if (sortCount < count) Qt.callLater(sortStep);
    }
    function findInsertIndex(item, head, tail) {
        if (head >= count)  return head;
        let cmp = sortCompare(item, get(head));
        if (cmp <= 0) return head;
        cmp = sortCompare(item, get(tail));
        if (cmp === 0) return tail;
        if (cmp > 0) return tail + 1;
        while (head + 1 < tail) {
            let mid = (head + tail) >> 1;
            cmp = sortCompare(item, get(mid));
            if (cmp === 0) return mid;
            if (cmp > 0) head = mid; else tail = mid;
        }
        return tail;
    }
    function sortItem(index) {
       if (index === 0) return;
       let newIndex = findInsertIndex(get(index), 0, index - 1);
       if (newIndex === index) return;
       move(index, newIndex, 1);
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        append( { "name": "fred", dob: (new Date("1980-01-01")).getTime() } );
        append( { "name": "wilma", dob: (new Date("1985-01-01")).getTime() } );
        append( { "name": "barney", dob: (new Date("1981-01-01")).getTime() } );
        append( { "name": "betty", dob: (new Date("1983-01-01")).getTime() } );
    }
}
```

I have a more comprehensive implementation of the above solution here:

- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-sortlistmodel